# How to increase bitmap size without losing its quality

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

Hi so i create a bitmap whit the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

and after that i compressed and scaled it in jpg file whit 100% quality,after that i saved it in a new file but after i send the email the image was blurry

this is how i created and scaled the image:

```
imgBitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgBitmap, 640,640, true);
```

So can you guys give me a code sample or links to how i can do it?

Comment: Use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to have a full-size photo be written to the location that you designate. Your current approach is giving you a small thumbnail image.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry to ask you this but where exactly to put EXTRA_OUTPUT? i'm a newbie in android :(

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath). See also [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android).